# How to reference a variable in Azure Devops on an Linux Agent which contains a dash/minus/-

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There is [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/alias-names-with-hyphens-create-invalid-environmen/428142) question which asks about using variables with a minus on linux agents. I tried an indirect reference as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-name-include-a-hyphen-or-dash) by doing `${!RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__BUILDPROJECT_SOURCEBRANCH}` but this does not work, and causes an error in my pipeline. I tried some other approaches using the `env` command but they too throw errors... Seems odd that this issue persists I guess not as much attention is put on Linux Agents as to Windows. But I am wondering if anyone has found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code on a Linux agent with variables with dashes.

Try running a bash task and running `printenv` which will show you all variables available in the linux agent.

Please clarify further what you are trying to do because I can see vars with dashes are working fine in the Linux agents.

```
pool: default

variables:
- name: test
  value: test-value-with-dashes
- name: test-name
  value: test-name-with-dashes
- name: System.Debug
  value: true

trigger:
- never

stages:
  - stage: approval_check
    jobs:
    - job: bash
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # Write your commands here
            set -x
            echo $(test)
            echo $(test-name)
            echo "print all env vars"
            printenv
```

And here is the output of `printenv` you can see the vars available in the build agent.

```
echo test-value-with-dashes
echo test-name-with-dashes
echo 'print all env vars'
printenv
.... lots of env vars printed...
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH=refs/heads/main
BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY=/home/james/_work/3/a
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but when you include build jobs in a release pipeline, variables such as BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH become `RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__{your project}_SOURCEBRANCH=` and if `your project` has a dash, then the variable name will have a dash. And then it seems impossible to reference, even tried printenv | grep '..' and saving that to another variable but does not work.